# count a specifc word in a text file in C#

Tags: c#

If i got a text file

"dont run if you cant hide, or you will be broken in two strings, your a evil man"

and i want to count how many times the word you is in the text file, and put that value in to a int variable.

how do i go about doing somthing like that?

Comment: no its work related im seting up a counter in Dispacher tool im creating, the string is just a sample. the file im using is a huge log file.

Comment: This is most certainly a homework question - and those that answered below should have 'taught' rather than 'done'.

Comment: @modsuck - because the log file is huge, you may not be able to read the whole thing into memory and use the Regex solutions below.

Comment: @Shane - I think we should take the OP at his word. Perhaps it is HW and he invented the story about reading log files. However, I don't think any good will come of us calling eachother liars.

Comment: calling me a liar wont do no good no,, thx for the ones that helping tho.

my webpage is over at www.systemio.net and as you can see im well in to my leraning curve of .net but i still got a long way to go and need help on many things.

Comment: if you look down at that page you will find som SS of the dispatcher tool im working on. You thinking my question be home work related is because i formated the line for easy understanding for the Peoples trying to help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming there are regular line breaks then if the file is huge this would be less memory intensive than some other approaches here. Uses Jason's counting method:

```
        var total = 0;
        using(StreamReader sr=new StreamReader("log.log"))
        {

            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                var counts = sr
                    .ReadLine()
                    .Split(' ')
                    .GroupBy(s => s)
                    .Select(g => new{Word = g.Key,Count = g.Count()});
                var wc = counts.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Word == "you");
                total += (wc == null) ? 0 : wc.Count;
            }
        }
```

<strike>Or, combining the Scoregraphic's answer here with a IEnumerable method:</strike>

```
    static IEnumerable<string> Lines(string filename)
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(filename))
        {
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                yield return sr.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

You could get a nifty one-liner

```
    Lines("log.log")
        .Select(line => Regex.Matches(line, @"(?i)\byou\b").Count)
        .Sum();
```

#### [Edited because System.IO.File now supports enumerating the lines of a file, removing need for hand rolled method of doing the same thing described above]

Or using framework method [`File.ReadLines()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you could reduce this to:

```
File.ReadLines("log.log")
        .Select(line => Regex.Matches(line, @"(?i)\byou\b").Count)
        .Sum();
```

Comment: I have a situation where the word you occurs more than once in a line and then I get an exception sequence contains more than 1 element.How to I solve this?

Answer (score 13):

To say it with a Regex...

```
Console.WriteLine((new Regex(@"(?i)you")).Matches("dont run if you cant hide, or you will be broken in two strings, your a evil man").Count)
```

or if you need the word you as stand-alone

```
Console.WriteLine((new Regex(@"(?i)\byou\b")).Matches("dont run if you cant hide, or you will be broken in two strings, your a evil man").Count)
```

**Edit:** Replaced \s+you\s+ with (?i)\byou\b for the sake of correctness

Comment: To be really complete, you'd need to allow for capitalization, punctuation, and the word appearing at the beginning or end of the sentence.

Comment: You're right, but he should get the idea (that's what it's about)

Comment: Almost, but not quite - your "standalone" version won't match a "you" at the beginning or end of the string. Use @"\byou\b", which matches at a word boundary.

Answer (score 10):

```
string s = "dont run if you cant hide, or you will be broken in two strings, your a evil man";
var wordCounts = from w in s.Split(' ')
                 group w by w into g
                 select new { Word = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };

int youCount = wordCounts.Single(w => w.Word == "you").Count;
Console.WriteLine(youCount);
```

Ideally punctuation should be ignored. I'll let you handle a messy detail like that.

Comment: Nice. If I were his teacher I'd never believe he came up with that himself ;^)

Comment: This will throw an InvalidOperationException if the word does not appear in the file instead of returning zero because of using Enumerable.Single().

Comment: And, for grins and giggles, you can use PLINQ to scale the query by adding .AsParallel() to the end of the from line as so:

... from w in s.Split(' ').AsParallel()

Answer (score 4):

Reading from a file:

```
int count;

using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("fileName")
{
   string contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
   MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(contents, "\byou\b");
   count = matches.Count;
}
```

Note that if you use "`\byou\b`" will match just the word "you" by itself. If you want to match "you" inside of other words (for example, the "you" in "your"), use "you" as the pattern instead of "\byou\b".

Answer (score 2):

try regular expressions:

```
Regex r = new Regex("test");
MatchCollection matches = r.Matches("this is a test of using regular expressions to count how many times test is said in a string");
int iCount = matches.Count;
```

Answer (score 1):

The following method will do the job.

```
public Int32 GetWordCountInFile(String fileName, String word, Boolean ignoreCase)
{
    return File
        .ReadAllText(fileName)
        .Split(new [] { ' ', '.', ',' })
        .Count(w => String.Compare(w, word, ignoreCase));
}
```

Maybe you will have to add a few other possible separators to the `String.Split()` call.

Answer (score 1):

Try counting the occurances using indexOf and then moving to the next entry. E.g.

```
using System;

namespace CountOcc
{
 class Program
 {
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
   int         StartPos; // Current pos in file.

   System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader( "c:\\file.txt" );
   String Str = sr.ReadToEnd();

   int Count = 0;
   StartPos = 0;
   do
   {
    StartPos = Str.IndexOf( "Services", StartPos );
    if ( StartPos >= 0 )
    {
     StartPos++;
     Count++;
    }
   } while ( StartPos >= 0 );

   Console.Write("File contained " + Count + " occurances");
   Console.ReadKey(true);
  }
 }
}
```