# Count how many times a "name" and "surname" is in a text in c# visual studio

Tags: c#

I want to be able to count a name and surname in C# with visual studio. Currently I can only search for 1 word in the text. I'm creating console applications using .NET 5.0 (current).

(When the input is "Harry" it counts how many times Harry has been found, when the input is "Harry Potter" it always counts as 0 even when there are multiple occurrences of "Harry Potter" in the text.)

Ive been looking for answers on google but can only find how to do count 1 word.

Here's my current code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Harry
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            StreamReader stream = File.OpenText("Harry Potter and the Sorcerer.txt");
            string text = stream.ReadToEnd();

            string woord = "";
            int count = 0;

            foreach (var item in text)
            {
                if (Char.IsLetter(item))
                {
                    woord = woord + item;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(woord == input)
                    {
                        count++; 
                    }
                    woord = "";
                }
            }
            Console.Write(input + ": " + count + " occurrences");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 'Harry Potter' contains a space, so `Char.IsLetter(item)`returns false.

Comment: Maybe `int count = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(text, input).Count;`

Comment: -Auditive, I added this into my code, now it does count the full string "Harry Potter". But it count's it one time less than it actually exists in the text (29 times instead of 30 times). Is it because the text starts with "Harry Potter"? Because other words I count are correctly counted.

Comment: Sure, https://paste.ee/p/KEMVO (I did it in paste;ee because it couldn't be posted in pastebin  it includes offensive content??). Ive currently added an if the input is harry potter the count will go up by 1 at the start so the end result is 30. But I would like to know why it counts it as 29 without the extra +1

Comment: If `Matches().Count` returns `29` - then in source string only 29 **exact** matches of `input`. Note about case-sensitiveness, multi-whitespaces etc.

Comment: Look at line 2709 or your text: "HARRY POTTER!". It's uppercased. Just add `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` and you'll get 30 occurencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps, in line with Auditive's suggestion:

```
int count = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(text, input, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Count
```

If you're still short, change input so it has the value `harry\s+potter`, the `\s+` meaning "at least one whitespace", just in case your text has `harrySPACESPACEpotter`.. (and welcome to the wonderful, arcane world of regular expressions)

And if you're still short I think you might have a spelling error in the document!

--

If you want to count Harry Or Potter you can tweak your Regex to `harry|potter`..

--

Other ways of solving this challenge exist, a typical one being to check the length of the array you get by splitting:

```
int count = text.Split(input).Length - 1;
```

If there are 5 Harry Potters, you'll get a 6 long array out of Split, hence the -1. It's potentially a bit more resource intensive though; if you're after the lowest possible CPU burn you're probably looking at something like:

```
int count=0;
for(int idx = text.IndexOf(input); idx > -1; count++, idx = text.IndexOf(input, idx+input.Length));
```

This sets a variable for counting then uses IndexOf repeatedly until it returns -1. Every time after the first time, the IndexOf starts from the end of the string it found last time. There is no loop body, everything happens in the header.

Worth pointing out that neither of these are case insensitive, but can be made so with more work

Comment: oooh okay, thank you for your answers (Caius Jard, Auditive) you really helped me out! :)

Comment: I think `Split` may be used if needed to count occurencies or each word in input, separated with whitespace `" "`. E.g. how many occurencies of Harry and of Potter separately: `"Harry Potter".Split(' ').ToList().ForEach(inputWord => Console.WriteLine("There is " + Regex.Matches(source, inputWord, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Count + " of word \"" + inputWord + "\"."));`

Comment: -Auditive The " RegexOptions.IgnoreCase" did the job, but I might as well try what you suggest!

Comment: @Caius Jard also, `text.Split(input)` wouldn't work as this `Split` overload accepts only chars array. Probably `text.Split(new string[] { input }, StringSplitOptions.None).Length` (without `- 1`) may do the trick (at test it gives 30 occurrencies too).

Comment: @Auditive relevant overload of Split is `public string[] Split (string? separator, StringSplitOptions options = System.StringSplitOptions.None);` - but if .net framework is in use then yes, your pattern. Split produces one more entry than there are search terms: ababa split on b produces 3 a for 2 b hence -1. No need for `Split(' ')`; `Split()` works for that

Comment: @Caius Jard and there in `Split` is no option to control char cases. You need manually lowercase or uppercase, such as `text.ToLower().Split(new string[] { input.ToLower() }, StringSplitOptions.None).Length - 1` (yep, here `-1` neccessary).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex and the File.ReadLines("File.txt") here you can see it:
[count a specifc word in a text file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427149/count-a-specifc-word-in-a-text-file-in-c-sharp/1427176)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the link you send me is for 1 word ("you") that's what I currently have. If I add another word separated with a space ("you fish") I would have the same problem.